# Python Pandas read csv file with variable preamble length

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm using pandas to read in a series of files and concatenate them to a dataframe. My files have a bunch of garbage at the beginning, of variable length, that I want to ignore. `pd.read_csv()` has the skiprows method. I've written a function to handle this case, but I have to open the file twice to make it work. Is there a better way?

```
HEADER = '#Start'

def header_index(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fp:
        for ind, line in enumerate(fp):
            if line.startswith(HEADER):
                return ind

for row in directories:
    path2file = '%s%s%s' % (path2data, row, suffix)
    myDF = pd.read_csv(path2file, skiprows=header_index(path2file), header=0, delimiter='\t')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the module StringIo which you can use just like a file handle, so you can strip some data, dump the clean stuff into a virtual file handle, and your csv reader will be none the wiser

Comment: your solution is how I would do it unless there is some penalty to opening the files - for example being quite large. but even then you could iterate though the lines without loading it into memory so I think you are spot-on.

Answer (score 1):

This would now be possible (don't know if it was possible back then) as follows:

```
pos= 0
oldpos = None

while pos != oldpos:  # make sure we stop reading, in case we reach EOF
    line= fp.readline()
    if line.startswith(HEADER):
        # set the read position to the start of the line
        # so pandas can read the header
        fp.seek(pos)
        break
    oldpos= pos
    pos= fp.tell()    # renenber this position as sthe start of the next line

pd.read_csv(fp, ...your options here...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `read_csv()` also accepts a file like object, you can skip the leading junk lines before passing that object --- instead of passing the file name.

Example:

Replace

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=no_junk_lines(filename), ...)
```

with:

```
def forward_csv(f, prefix):
    pos = 0
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line or line.startswith(prefix):
            f.seek(pos)
            return f
        pos += len(line.encode('utf-8'))

df = pd.read_csv(forward_csv(open(filename), HEADER), ...)
```

Notes:

- `readline()` returns the empty string when EOF is reached
- not invoking `tell()` for keeping track of the position saves some `lseek` system calls
- the last line of `forward_csv()` assumes that your input file is encoded in ASCII or UTF-8 - if it isn't you have to adjust this line